# WPF: Adding a Separator to a Context Menu defined in Resources

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, contextmenu, separator

I have a `ContextMenu` that is being defined in `Resources`. To be more specific, this context menu is used for a `DataGrid`, and is to appear when a row is being right-clicked. Because of that, I cannot use `<DataGrid.ContextMenu>` to define this context menu, I needed to do this:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource DataGridCM}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>

<ContextMenu x:Key="DataGridCM"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}">
    <MenuItem Header="Item 1" Command="{Binding Command1}" />
    <MenuItem Header="Item 2" Command="{Binding Command2}" />
    <Separator />
    <MenuItem Header="Other Item" Command="{Binding OtherCommand}" />      
</ContextMenu>
```

This gave me this error:

```
A style intended for type 'MenuItem' cannot be applied to type 'Separator'.
```

Is there any method to add the `Separator` in? I have tried `ItemsSource` shown below but it still gave me the same runtime error.

```
<ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
        <MenuItem Header="Item 1" Command="{Binding Command1}" />
        <MenuItem Header="Item 2" Command="{Binding Command2}" />
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Other Item" Command="{Binding OtherCommand}" />  
    </CompositeCollection>
 </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
```

I know this can be done if I use code-behind, but I would want to avoid that because I am using MVVM. I do not wish that other people taking over my project years later would get confused by a single View class with code-behind. Is there any way to solve this probably purely from XAML level?

Comment: The error msg you have posted is not because of the `Style` shown in the above code, because that `Style` is targeting `DataGridRow`, not `MenuItem`. Is there any other `Style` in action here?

Comment: Wow, you are amazing, it's indeed something else that is causing the problem. My old implementation was using a `ItemsSource` bound context menu, It was using a custom ICommand implementation with a "Header" property. which I used `ItemContainerStyle` to define Header text.